# Is there any way to make SVGs editable after loading them back onto the viewer with MarkupsCore?

Tags: javascript, svg, autodesk-forge

So, I am currently running into the problem that after a user makes a markup, and I store it to the database, when I reload it, it is no longer able to be edited. I realize that the api was designed this way, but I am wondering if there is a way to add the markups back and still be able to change the text, move them, etc.

I really have no ideas, so any help or direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit saved markups as follow. This feature has been added to the API in [release 2.16](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/overview/changelog/2.16/):

```
// string with markups data generated with markupsExt.generateData()
var modelMarkups = '...';

// Load the markups extension
viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore').then(function(markupsExt){

    markupsExt.show();

    // Load markups onto "layerA"
    markupsExt.loadMarkups(modelMarkups, "layerA"); 

     // Allow editing of markups in "layerA"
    markupsExt.enterEditMode("layerA");            
})
```

Comment: So, I have one more question, and I very much appreciate your help. Do you guys provide some kind of function to spawn markups from scripts? Like, can I spawn a textbox that says Hello World from a script in a specific place?

Comment: When you guys refer to a layer in markupscore, what is this? Is it a canvas, or?

Comment: You can use the generateData  member method on the MarkupsCore extension instance to save current markups to a string, save the string where ever you need, in a database for example, and load the markups from that string at a later time. There is no API to directly create markups programmatically if that is what you mean, but I assume it could be doable, you would need to look a bit deeper in the code of the MarkupsCore. About layers: when you load markups you specify a name, which can be though as a "layer", you then turn each layers ON or OFF from the API.

Comment: Here is a live demo using the markup API that can save markup data in a side database: https://forge-rcdb.autodesk.io/configurator?id=598d7ec14cabf2c1f4dec948. The code for it is there: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs/tree/master/src/client/viewer.components/Viewer.Extensions.Dynamic/Viewing.Extension.Markup2D